# Remove directory after copy it XCOPY

Tags: c#, xcopy

I'm working with C#, using `XCOPY`. I have method which copies a full directory into another:

```
 public static void ProcessXcopy(string SolutionDirectory, string TargetDirectory)
        {
            // Use ProcessStartInfo class
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            //Give the name as Xcopy
            startInfo.FileName = "xcopy";

            //make the window Hidden
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            //Send the Source and destination as Arguments to the process
            startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + SolutionDirectory + "\"" + " " + "\"" + TargetDirectory + "\"" + @" /e /y /I /B";

            try
            {
                // Start the process with the info we specified.
                // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw exp;
            }
        }
```

That I want to know if there is a way to remove source directory once it is copied to another directory successfully.

Comment: XCopy is for use from the command line. Why are you using it instead of doing this directly from your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick .Net Methods, you can use Directory.Delete in the finally statement . The second parameter indicates to remove the Sub Folder/Files. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_Delete_System_String_System_Boolean_)

```
Directory.Delete(path,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `robocopy` instead of `xcopy`

```
robocopy from_folder to_folder files_to_copy /MOVE
```

`xcopy` needs `.bat` script in order to have same functionality with 1 line of `robocopy`

Ex:

```
xcopy /D /V %1 %2

if errorlevel 0 (
    del /Q %1
    exit /B
)
```